# R code chunks error

Tags: r

It's my first time to work with code chunks but I can not run any code with the code chunk. For example if I run following code:

````
```{r}
print('Hello')
```
````

I get a `Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name`. It seems R does not recognise the syntax. On this [page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html) it looks like a built-in feature of R, however I can not drill more information about the feature itself.

I have tested on both `R for 3.2.4 GUI 1.67 Mavericks build (7152)` and `RStudio
Version 0.99.896` on Mac OS 10.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you typing this into the R command prompt? Because that's how I can get that error:

````
> ```{r}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> print('Hello')
[1] "Hello"
> ```
````

This is **knitr** markdown syntax and needs to go into a file to be processed by `knitr`. What are you doing with it? Are you running it through `source`? It needs to go through `knitr`. Read a basic `knitr` documentation.

Comment: Yes, as I said `source` will do the same. Start here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html  put your code into a `.Rmd` file and process it as explained with `render`.

Comment: Okay I do not know I have to deal with `knitr` since it is the first time for me to use it. I will try now.